# Torch image.load() doesn't work well with named pipes

Tags: deep-learning, torch

To reproduce this:

```
require 'image'
img = image.load('input_pipe')
image.display(img)
```

On another terminal, run:

```
mkfifo input_pipe
cat <image_file> > input_pipe
```

Notice that calling `cat <image_file> > input_pipe` once doesn't load the image. You have to call it twice. My guess is that `image.load` opens the file twice. Any help/alternative would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/v97PKAdQrzE). Apparently, `image.load()` opens the image file to find out the file type and then opens it again to call the respective image loader e.g. `image.loadJPG()`